# Is there a measure to describe the degree of linear separability?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

I know that given two sets of points, one can use linear programming to see if there is a solution/hyperplane that linearly separates the two data sets. But this holds for completely linearly separability. I wonder in case that the two sets can only be linearly separated by neglecting some points in both sets, then is there a measure to describe the degree of linear separability?

---

In other ways, the problem may be transformed to

> At least how many points we need to kick out to have linear
>   separability? (and the degree may be measured by the number of points
>   to be kicked out divided by sample size)

But is this computationally expensive to implement using computers? Or is there any better way to measure the degree of linear separability?